# Keyword tokenizer vs not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

When specifying a filter using **term**, should the field always be **not_analyzed** or can it use the **keyword** analyzer? For example:

```
        "must_not": [
          {
            "term": {
              "personid": "ABADF00D-BEEF-4218-B59B-A164017A3BA0"
            }
          },
```

If I want to look for that personid case insensitive, I might use a keyword tokenizer with lowercase filter. But that seems to be causing it to not work when used as a **term**. Should I stick to the **not_analyzed** in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a field as `not_analyzed` is equivalent to using the `keyword` tokenizer without any other filters (i.e. no `lowercase`).

If you want to be able to search for that field in a case-insensitive way, yet still allow for `term` queries, you have two options.

Option A: Use a `keyword` tokenizer + `lowercase` token filter as you do now but make sure to lowercase the value in your `term` query, i.e.

```
    "must_not": [
      {
        "term": {
          "personid": "abadf00d-beef-4218-b59b-a164017a3ba0"
        }
      },
```

Option B: Use a `keyword` tokenizer + `lowercase` token filter as you do now (named `your_analyzer` below) but also add a sub-field `raw` which you declare as `not_analyzed`. So your mapping would basically look like this:

```
{
  "personid": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "your_analyzer",
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you'd run your `term` query on the `personid.raw` subfield and if you want to search case-insensitively, then you'd run the query on the `personid` field

```
    "must_not": [
      {
        "term": {
          "personid.raw": "ABADF00D-BEEF-4218-B59B-A164017A3BA0"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if the term is used in a filter (as opposed to in a query)?

Comment: There's no more difference between queries and filters since ES 2.x

Comment: Oh we are still in 1.7, moving up to  supported versions soon.

Comment: Then use `term` in a filter indeed.